# Find the depth of the current path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, fish

How can I write a shell script to find the depth of the current path?

Assuming I am in:

```
/home/user/test/test1/test2/test3
```

It should return 6.

Comment: Hint: use `string split` and `count`

Comment: Why are you tagging this question with both "bash" and "fish"? Those two shells do not support the same syntax. Your question is overly broad.

Comment: Kurtis, thanks for participating. I have looked online and could not find a script that does that even in bash. Given that fish is newish I did not expect many responses so I was willing to get a bash script and try to convert it myself. That was my rational. Sorry if this was the wrong thing to do. Is it possible for me to remove a tag? I will check.

Comment: Well, now you removed the [tag:bash] tag... implicitly invalidating the answers that are Bash specific.

Comment: Banjamin, I truly appreciate your write up and proposed solution. I did not know removing the tag from the post will have such an effect. There was no question asked that tackle the depth issue even in bash so I reinstated the tag since your answer has a great value for people interested in bash. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach in fish:

```
count (string split / $PWD)
```

Answer (score 8):

With shell parameter expansions, no external commands:

```
$ var=${PWD//[!\/]}
$ echo ${#var}
6
```

The first expansion removes all characters that are not `/`; the second one prints the length of `var`.

---

Explanations with details for support by POSIX shell or Bash (the links in parentheses go to the corresponding sections in the POSIX standard or the Bash manual):

- `$PWD` contains the path to the current working directory. *([sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03)/[Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PWD))*
- The `${parameter/pattern/string}` expansion replaces the first occurrence of *`pattern`* in the expansion of *`parameter`* with *`string`*. *([Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))*

  - If the first slash is doubled (as in our case), *all* occurrences are replaced.
  - If *`string`* is empty, the slash after *`pattern`* is optional  (as in our case).
- The pattern `[!\/]` is a bracket expression and stands for "any character other than slash". *([sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01)/[Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching))*

  - The slash has to be escaped, `\/`, or it is interpreted as ending the pattern.
  - `!` as the first character in a bracket expression negates the expression: any character *other* than the ones in the expression match the pattern. POSIX sh requires support for `!` and says the behaviour for using `^` is undefined; Bash supports both `!` and `^`. Notice that this is not a bracket expression as seen in regular expressions, where only `^` is valid.
- `${#parameter}` expands to the length of *`parameter`*. *([sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)/[Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))*

Comment: Can you explain `[!\/]` please ? I'm not aware about the `!` in this context. +1 for the most concise way :) And maybe you can add precisions about wich shells can do this

Comment: @GillesQuenot The `!` as the negating character in a shell pattern bracket expression is required by POSIX, whereas the behvaviour for `^` is undefined; Bash supports both `!` and `^`. I'll add a bit more information.

Answer (score 3):

You could count the number of slashes in the current path:

```
pwd | awk -F"/" '{print NF-1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a pipeline. pipe string into grep with the -o option. This prints out each "/" on a new line. pipe again into wc -l counts the number of lines printed.

```
echo "$path_str" | grep -o '/' - | wc -l
```

Comment: I like this because it would work in a minimal shell like ash/dash. You should quote `$path_str`, though, or you can run into nasty surprises if your string contains globbing characters. POSIX requires `$PWD`, by the way, so you could use that.

Comment: Good point about the quote. Could you clarify POSIX requiring $PWD? I'm afraid I don't have extensive experience with linux just yet.

Comment: Instead of using `$path_str`, to which you'd have to assign the current path, you can use the environment variable `$PWD`, which is required to exist if a shell wants to be compliant with POSIX, which is a compatibility standard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have trailing "/", you can just count the "/".

So you would

- Remove everything that is not a "/"
- Count the length of the resulting string

In fish, this would be done with something like

```
string replace --regex --all '[^/]' '' -- $PWD | string length
```

The regular expression - `[^/]` here matches every single character that is not a "/". With "--all", this will be done as often as possible, and replace it with `''`, i.e. nothing.

The `--` is the option separator, so that nothing in the argument is interpreted as an option (otherwise you'd have issues if an argument started with a "-a").

`$PWD` is the current directory.

`string length` simply outputs the length of its input.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to have the count in a variable that I check later. How do I set length to the output as a number (not string)? would this work? "set length string replace --regex --all '[^/]' '' -- $PWD" then later I could do "if test $length -lt 7"

Comment: `string length` does turn it into a number, so you could put that into a variable and use it later. `set length (string replace --regex --all '[^/]' '' -- $PWD | string length); if test $length -lt 7`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
echo '/home/user/test/test1/test2/test3' | 
perl -lne '@_ = split /\//; print scalar @_ -1'
```

### Output

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` just like that :

```
find / -printf "%d %p\n" 2>/dev/null | grep "$PWD$" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Maybe not the most efficient, but handles slashes well.