# How do count the amount of levels in a filepath including the root? (Shell scripting)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to create a script that will take an input argument (filepath) and count the amount of levels are in the filepath. I tried to use the following code but it only counts the home and directories, but not the root and file if specified.

```
IFS="/" read -ra PARTS <<< "$(pwd)"                                                                                                                                                                                                          
for i in "${PARTS[@]}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 echo "$i"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 ((NUM_FLEVEL=NUM_FLEVEL+1))                                                                                                                                                                                                          
done
```

Say that I type in "script ~/hello1/file1" and the ~ happens to be **home/house**. I expect the actual total count to be 5.

1. /
2. home
3. house
4. hello1
5. file1

Comment: You just want the actual total? like the number 5? please clarify that.

Comment: Yes the actual total.

Comment: Andrew Then @tripleee already has your answer.

Comment: @Andrew: _Say that I type in "script ~/hello1/file1" _ ... You want to pass a parameter to your script, but you don't fetch this parameter anywhere.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816827/find-the-depth-of-the-current-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are operating on the ouput of `pwd`, not on the file name you apparently tried to pass in as a command-line argument.

You can print the length of an array simply with `${#array[@]}`.

```sh
IFS="/" read -ra PARTS <<< "$1"
echo "${#PARTS[@]}"
```

Demo (with some debugging details): https://ideone.com/1oWawt

A proper solution would probably loop over `"$@"` so you can pass in multiple arguments.

Comment: Well i feel silly now.. haha. Do you happen to know what command can trace a filepath starting from the root?

Comment: What do you mean by "trace a filepath`? Anyway, probably ask a separate question on [unix.se] with more detils.

Comment: Well.. I would like to be able to count the number of levels in a filepath. So if a user provides a relative filepath, the script will count the amount of levels including the root.

Comment: @Andrew, that is not part of your original question/post. What you have asked was answered already

Comment: I literally just posted a script which does this. I don't think there is a separate tool because this is so trivial to write on your own. `awk -F / '{ print NF, $0 }'` if you want to pass in a text file.

Comment: I had forgotten to add the #. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: @Andrew: You did not specify in your question, what output you expect from `script ././.` or from `script ~/hello/` (note the final `/` in the latter). Depending on your requirements, the solution posted by tripleee will or will not do the job.

Comment: There are tools like `abspath` and `relpath` for normalizing paths but they are not standard and portable.